# On difference identities and $[K:F]$

Tags: fields, difference-equations

Let $(K,\sigma)$ be a *difference field* of characteristic $0$, *i.e.* equiped with field morphism $\sigma:K\rightarrow K$. Assume that $K$ satisfy a non-trivial univariate difference polynomial identity $\delta=0$ for some $\delta\in K\{x\}$, where $$K\{x\}=K\left[\sigma^i(x):i\in\mathbb N\right].$$ Let $F=\{x\in K:\sigma x=x\}$ be the subfield fixed by $\sigma$.

> > **Question.** Is $[K:F]$ finite?

**Remark.**   The answer is yes if the identity is of 'degree 1', i.e. of the form $$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\sigma^k(x)=a_{{-1}}$$ for some $a_{-1},a_0,\dots,a_n\in K$, and conversely, a finite dimensional $F$-algebra satisfies such an identity.

**Edit.** The following question is motivated by the question:

> > **Question.** Is the evaluation map that maps a difference polynomial  $\delta\in K\{x\}$ to the function $\delta_K:K\rightarrow K$ is injective, at least when $[K:F]$ is infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes and appears in R. Cohn's book 'Difference algebra' Lemma II p. 201.